# How to detect if the event is a browser event or not

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How would you test if an event is a browser event (e.g. `click`, `load`, `blur` etc) based on its name (e.g. `click`)? (and *no* I'm not using jQuery/mootools/prototype/dojo)

**UPDATE**:

In this function I attach browser events (`click` and `load`) for example:

```
observe: function(elements, eventName, callback) {
  if (!(elements.length != null)) {
    elements = [elements];
  }
  return this.each(elements, function(e) {
    if (helper.hooks.eventObserved != null) {
      helper.hooks.eventObserved(eventName, callback, e);
    }
    if (typeof e === 'string') {
      e = this.el(e);
    }
    if (e.addEventListener) {
      return e.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    } else if (e.attachEvent) {
      return e.attachEvent("on" + eventName, callback);
    }
  });
},
```

And this fires the event:

```
fire: function(elements, eventName) {
  if (!(elements.length != null)) {
    elements = [elements];
  }
  return this.each(elements, function(e) {
    var evt;
    if (document.createEventObject != null) {
      evt = document.createEventObject();
      return e.fireEvent("on" + eventName);
    } else {
      evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
      evt.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
      return !e.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
  });
},
```

But what I want is to test if the event exists for example `click` is a browser event but `login` isn't so how would I test that?

Comment: If you're not using jquery/mootools/prototype/dojo, then where would the events be coming from if they're not "browser events"?

Comment: (Note that I'm resisting the temptation to guess that your a Qooxdoo user.)

Comment: I'm writing my own small JS library

Comment: I don't understand this question. What do you mean by a "browser" event? Where are these events coming from? Can you give an example in code of a problem you want to overcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this solution](http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/) by [Juriy Zaytsev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130652/kangax) ([live demo](http://kangax.github.com/iseventsupported/)).

jQuery itself uses it.

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if the function/object `element["on"+event]` exists:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="myAnchor">test</a>
<script>

function doesElementHaveEvent(element, event){
    return (typeof element["on"+event] != typeof undefined);
}

alert(doesElementHaveEvent(document.getElementById("myAnchor"), "click")); // true
alert(doesElementHaveEvent(document.getElementById("myAnchor"), "login")); // false
</script>
```